# Can I interact my randomly-assigned variable with another variable in TSLS?

Tags: r, assumptions, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I'm working on an IV setup that uses random courtroom assignment as an instrument for whether a defendant goes to jail or not. (Similar to [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nber.org%2Fpapers%2Fw15602&ei=P77cVPnnF8GpgwTNi4ToAg&usg=AFQjCNGB0NqnJ2YxJ5wmiW6QCNsAGUkIrQ&sig2=B6Wv4PqzlEafuw1cLBGY9g&bvm=bv.85761416,d.eXY) and others).  I have about five years of courtroom data, and then an outcome variable that happens at one point in time for all defendants (so imagine that I have courtroom data for 2000-2005, and then an outcome measured in 2006 for all defendants, regardless of when they faced charges).  I want to know if jail time affects my outcome variable.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set up the instruments.

One obvious approach is just to instrument with dummy variables for each courtroom (including all but one of the dummies).  But I'm worried about non-monotonicity-- in practice, over time the courtrooms shift in harshness, such that courtroom 1 might give out harsher sentences than courtroom 4 in 2002, but in 2004 courtroom 4 is harsher than courtroom 1.  Further cause for concern: when I run this specification (instrumenting for jail with the courtroom dummies), I find a nearly-zero effect of jail on my outcome variable.  But if I subset the data by year and re-run it, in each individual year I find a substantial effect in the same direction (though with p-values ranging from .15 to .3).

I found [this paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~mgm2146/incar.pdf), which is using very similar data to mine.  There's a simple example on pg. 12 demonstrating exactly the type of pattern I find above, though the non-monotonicity there is by case type rather than case year.  The author "solves" this problem by replacing the court-dummy instruments with the interaction of court dummies and case types.  I think the equivalent here would be for me to interact the court dummies with case years (also including the main effect for year/court?) in the IV setup?

I've done this, so using the `AER` package in `R` to run TSLS my setup looks like this:

```
original   <- ivreg(outcome ~ jail | crt_2 + crt_3 + crt_4 + crt_5 + crt_6 + crt_7 +
                                     crt_8 + crt_9 + crt_10 + crt_11 + crt_12 + crt_13 +
                                     crt_14 + crt_15, 
                    data=dataset)
interacted <- ivreg(outcome ~ jail | (crt_2 + crt_3 +crt_4 + crt_5 + crt_6 + crt_7 + 
                                      crt_8 + crt_9 + crt_10 + crt_11 + crt_12 +
                                      crt_13 + crt_14 + crt_15)*fyear, 
                    data=dataset)
```

I've tried running this, and it gives me results I find plausible.  I also ran a placebo test using several years of data from after my outcome variable was collected, and I didn't find any results, which is encouraging.  But I still can't quite wrap my head around how/whether this approach is okay.  If it is, I'll go ahead and set up the more complex approach that the Mueller-Smith paper proposes, throwing in all sorts of interactions and using a LASSO or post-LASSO to pare down the number of instruments.  But I just wanted to run this simple interaction setup by someone first.  Can I do this?